# Number soft keyboard showing comma not appearing when installed

Tags: android, keyboard

I have created an app for me and my coworkers to use which all it does is sort an ArrayList of numbers.  The coding for it works fine and the keyboard showing on my emulator is exactly the one I am looking for.  The problem came about when I installed it on my Samsung Galaxy S4 and it displayed a completely different number keypad.  I installed it on a friends S3 and he got a completely different number keypad than the other 2.

[image]

The only code that I have in place for the keyboard is as follows

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789,"
```

There might be a different inputType that I am unaware of which might be better to use for this but any and all help would be greatly appreciated on getting this figured out. Thanks in advance and I'd be more than happy to answer any and all questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a doucmented bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626 for this issue.

Workaroud for this :

```
public class DecimalKeyListener extends DigitsKeyListener {
    private final char[] acceptedCharacters =
    new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-',
        new DecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()};

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
    return acceptedCharacters;
    }

    public int getInputType() {
    return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    }

}

DecimalKeyListener myDecimalKeyListener = new DecimalKeyListener();

EditText e = ...
e.setKeyListener(myDecimalKeyListener);
```